# How do I use Pi4's GPIO pins with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

Ros2 works with Ubuntu 20.04 specifically. It should be easy to use the SBC GPIO pins, RaspberryPi4 runnung Ubuntu 64bit in my case.

There's wiringpi > it installs but when "gpio -v" is run, it errors? out with`Type Unknown17 .... Raspberry Pi 4 model B Rev1.1... This raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access`

Ubuntu admits GPIO does not work with 20.04 but is fixed in 20.1 !!ros only works with 20.04!! [How to use Raspberry Pi GPIO pins with Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/gpio-on-raspberry-pi#1-overview)

pip install RPI.GPIO seems to bring with it a lot of manual file changes witch normally does not work.

Then there's the install of a raspberry OS tool called RaspiConfig into Ubuntu 20.04. I haven't tried it but seems troublesome.

It must be such a simple solution that there's no tutorial or youtube video of using GPIO pins with Focal(20.04)    Please help

Comment: Have you tried it with Ubuntu 20.10? Ubuntu 21.04? Just because the docs say that it is targeted at a specific version doesn't mean that newer versions do not work. The Ros2 docs may not be updated.

Comment: I am guessing that you get 20.04 from the setup guide. If something in the guide is not working properly with newer versions, ask a question here, and we will most likely be able to help. Sooner or later, the documentation will likely be updated so that the newer versions are "supported."

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nate T, I have spend hours over weeks setting it all up. To start over is not an option.

Comment: you can use the command `do-release-upgrade` to auto-upgrade linux. Seems like your best option/ easiest fix. Just look it up first, 20.04 and 20.10 weren't that much different on the surface. You should be fine there. Can't speak for 21.04 yet. Regardless, a bit of up-front homework will always save time & stress in the long run.